# How to compare each row of data frame 1 with each row of data frame 2?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have two data frames that look like this:

```
x=data.frame(Name=c("200003","200260","400826","400863","500710"),Chr=c("chr1","chr1","chr2","chr3","chr3"),Position=c(11880,14415,13000,15000,18000))    
y=data.frame(name=c("geneA","geneB","geneC","geneD","geneE"),chrom=c("chr1","chr1","chr2","chr2","chr3"),Start=c(11873,11878,12000,14361,14361),End=c(14409,14419,14409,16765,19759))

> x
    Name  Chr Position
1 200003 chr1    11880
2 200260 chr1    14415
3 400826 chr2    13000
4 400863 chr3    15000
5 500710 chr3    18000

> y
   name chrom   Start   End
1 geneA  chr1   11873 14409
2 geneB  chr1   11878 14419
3 geneC  chr2   12000 14409
4 geneD  chr2   14361 16765
5 geneE  chr3   14361 19759
```

I would like to compare x and y, and return a dataframe or list consisting of each Name in x and the names of y that has the same chrom as Chr and the (Start,End) interval includes the Position. For example,

```
200003  geneA
200003  geneB
200260  geneB
400826  geneC
400863  geneE
500710  geneE
```

Edit: I was able to get the result using the following code

```
z=merge(x,y,by.x='Chr',by.y='chrom')
z=cbind(z,with(z, Position>=Start & Position<=End))
z=z[-which(z[,7]=="FALSE"),]
output=cbind(as.character(z$Name),as.character(z$name))
```

In reality x and y and large datasets and it takes a while for `merge` to run. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is not an `apply` problem. You could create a useful if ponderous intermediate with `merge`.

Comment: Maybe with `split` or `data.table`? I'll see if I can cobble together a data.table approach. I'm not the  most adroit with DT. The new release has range functions. I've added a tag to see if there are any data.table-barracudas in this reef.

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@BondedDust seems to have removed his solution. The only issue with his solution is that the key needs to also include `chrom`.

Here's using `foverlaps` from `data.table`. First we'll convert the data.frames to data.tables:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(x)
setDT(y)
```

Then, since `foverlaps` works with interval ranges, we'll add a dummy column for `x` as follows:

```
x[, Position2 := Position]
```

Now, for each `x`, we'd like to know if `Chr, Position, Position2` falls entire *within* any `y`'s `chrome,Start,End`. We'll use `y` as "key" as follows:

```
setkey(y, chrom, Start, End)
foverlaps(x, y, by.x=c("Chr", "Position", "Position2"))[, list(Name, name)]
#      Name  name
# 1: 200003 geneA
# 2: 200003 geneB
# 3: 200260 geneB
# 4: 400826 geneC
# 5: 400863 geneE
# 6: 500710 geneE
```

The columns in your data.frames are unusually named and cased - "chrom" vs "Chr". It might be easier to work with consistent names.

Comment: This is amazingly fast! Although it generated more results than I did using the slow method (any ideas?). Guess I'll have to explore more powerful functions of `data.table`...

Comment: @Menglan, much glad! If you could link me to some test data (where the results differ), I'd he happy to take a look at it.

Comment: I did some testing on my own and found that it was because `foverlaps` had NA's when `Chr, Position, Position2` falls outside `chrome, Start, End` while such result would not show if I used my code. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. You can make use of `nomatch=0L` if you don't want to return `NA`for no matches.

Answer (score 2):

This gives more or less what you want (it's not ragged, the Name from `x` will repeat if there are multiple matches):

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select x.Name, y.name
  from x
  left join y
  on x.Position between y.Start and y.End
  and x.Chr = y.chrom")

    Name  name
1 200003 geneA
2 200003 geneB
3 200260 geneB
4 400826 geneC
5 400863 geneE
6 500710 geneE
```

Comment: I have trouble loading the package, but the output is acceptable. Thanks for the answer!